# "card" div having a grey space at the bottom, cannot make the background white as the rest of the card

Tags: css, card

Ill post some screenshots for better understanding. Anyone can help me making the grey space at the bottom of the card white?

[image: grey space bottom]

[image: css]

[image: creating UI]

[image: html div where adding all countries cards]

Thanks much!
Simon

Comment: You need to post a [mcve], not images of code

Answer (score 0):

Just add `align-items-stretch` class in your `d-flex` container

```
<div class="countries-list d-flex flex-wrap flex-row flex-end justify-content-between align-items-stretch">
```

Comment: Hey James, thanks for the reply! That did sadly not work for me. But I added h-100 to the text section of the card and this helped cause now the text is using 100% of the available height.